# User's home directory owned by root when syncing a folder with Vagrant and Ansible

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, ansible

I'm setting up an Ubuntu Vagrant environment (with VirtualBox provider) using Ansible. I'm syncing a directory on my host/local machine with the guest/Vagrant machine.

There [are issues](http://ryansechrest.com/2014/04/unable-set-permissions-within-shared-folder-using-vagrant-virtualbox/) with permissions for synced folders, and so I'm specifying the synced folder in my Vagrantfile like this:

```ruby
config.vm.synced_folder "./path/to/local/dir",
  "/home/deploy/webapps/myapp",
  owner: 5000, group: 5000, mount_options: ['dmode=775', 'fmode=664']
```

Then in an Ansible task, when I create the `deploy` user and group, I specify their `uid` and `gid` as `5000`. This seems to be one of the accepted ways to do things.

However, this results in the `deploy` user's home directory being owned by `root`, and not having its full complement of files:

```bash
deploy@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ ls -al /home
total 20
drwxr-xr-x  5 root    root    4096 Mar  1 17:20 .
drwxr-xr-x 23 root    root    4096 Mar  1 17:20 ..
drwxr-xr-x  5 root    root    4096 Mar  1 17:23 deploy
drwxr-xr-x  3 ubuntu  ubuntu  4096 Mar  1 17:19 ubuntu
drwxr-xr-x  5 vagrant vagrant 4096 Mar  1 17:20 vagrant

deploy@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ ls -al /home/deploy
total 24
drwxr-xr-x  5 root   root   4096 Mar  1 17:23 .
drwxr-xr-x  5 root   root   4096 Mar  1 17:20 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root    213 Mar  1 17:23 .bashrc
drwxr-xr-x 12 deploy deploy 4096 Mar  1 17:26 .pyenv
drwx------  2 deploy deploy 4096 Mar  1 17:20 .ssh
drwxr-xr-x  3 root   root   4096 Mar  1 17:20 webapps

deploy@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ ls -al /home/deploy/webapps
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 3 root   root   4096 Mar  1 17:20 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root   root   4096 Mar  1 17:23 ..
drwxrwxr-x 1 deploy deploy  850 Mar  1 14:53 myapp
```

By contrast, if I don't sync that folder in the Vagrantfile, then there are significant differences:

```bash
deploy@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ ls -al /home
total 20
drwxr-xr-x  5 root    root    4096 Mar  1 17:30 .
drwxr-xr-x 23 root    root    4096 Mar  1 17:30 ..
drwxr-xr-x  5 deploy  deploy  4096 Mar  1 17:37 deploy
drwxr-xr-x  3 ubuntu  ubuntu  4096 Mar  1 17:30 ubuntu
drwxr-xr-x  5 vagrant vagrant 4096 Mar  1 17:30 vagrant

deploy@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ ls -al /home/deploy/
total 32
drwxr-xr-x  5 deploy deploy 4096 Mar  1 17:37 .
drwxr-xr-x  5 root   root   4096 Mar  1 17:30 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 deploy deploy  220 Apr  9  2014 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r--  1 deploy deploy 3850 Mar  1 17:33 .bashrc
drwx------  2 deploy deploy 4096 Mar  1 17:37 .cache
-rw-r--r--  1 deploy deploy  675 Apr  9  2014 .profile
drwxr-xr-x 12 deploy deploy 4096 Mar  1 17:37 .pyenv
drwx------  2 deploy deploy 4096 Mar  1 17:30 .ssh
```

So, when syncing that directory, why is `/home/deploy` owned by `root`? And why doesn't the `deploy` user get `.profile`, `.bash_logout` etc files? And, most importantly, how do I correct this?

Comment: I'd love to know why this was moved from serverfault. I nearly posted it on stackoverflow – as most of my questions are asked here – but thought it seemed more like a serverfault thing and so asked it, as my very first question, there! Not a problem, I'm just curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know enough about Ubuntu etc to be 100% sure this is what's going on, but it seems reasonable...

I think that when creating that synced folder at `/home/deploy/webapps/myapp`, Vagrant is, understandably, creating the `/home/deploy` directory and its contents. Its owner:group is `root:root`.

So, later, when my Ansible playbook creates the `deploy` user, it sees it already has a home directory and doesn't bother with creating its `.bashrc` etc, or re-setting its user:group permissions.

So, to avoid this, I've synced the folder at `/webapps/myapp` instead, and changed my Ansible playbook to expect that location. Seems to work.